# How to perform open system call in linux only if file exists and only if file doesn't exists?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am learning Linux system calls right now and I came across `O_EXCL` and I had few doubts about `open` system call in linux. I have 2 specific doubts which are related to each other.

1. How to open a file (for say writing) only if it exists? Meaning I should not be able to open a file in this case, if it does not exist.
2. How to open a file (for say writing) only if it doesn't exist? Meaning I should not be able to open a file in this case, if it exists. This is similar to creating a file I guess, but I just want to create it and open it for writing, I don't want to open a file if it already exists.

So can you please give me the full `open` command for these two cases in Linux?

Thanks

Note: Also please explain your answer in brief, I did learn about different option flags like `O_EXCL`, `O_WRONLY` etc, but it would be better if I could some explanation about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, just use `O_WRONLY` - the file will not be created without `O_CREAT`.

In the second case, you use `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL`.

Comment: Yeah the first case makes sense, my bad I just was thinking too hard, and the second case I believe is something causing me a little trouble to understand.  What would happen if I used only `O_CREAT` or only `O_EXCL`in combination with `O_WRONLY` in your second statement?

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use the stat system call to find out whether the file exists. Then, if it exists, you can open the file with the flag, O_WRONLY.
2. If you find in #1 above that the file does not exist, you can open it with the flags, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT. Since you have already ensured that the file is not existing, O_EXCL is not required.

You can combine #1 and #2 by skipping the check with the stat system call and opening the file with O_WRONLY | O_CREAT. If the file already existed, it will be used for writing as in #1. If it did not exist, it will be created and used for writing as in #2.

Comment: Don't do this - you'll have a race condition. If the file is deleted (or created) after the `stat` call and before the `open` call, this won't work. @viraptor's solution is a much better one.